# How to get a certain field out of form in django template?

Tags: python, django

i wonder how i can add some extra html to a certain field in a template in Django

I have the following form (forms.py)

```
first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'required'}))
last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'required'}))
street = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'required'}))
```

In my template i get the fields with:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
     {% for field in form %}
             <div class="fieldWrapper">
             {{ field.errors }}
             {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

Now i want to add some extra html to the street field like this

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
     {% for field in form %}
             {% if field.type =='street' %}
                <div class="fieldWrapper otherclass">
                <hr>

             {% else %}
             <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {% endif %}

             {{ field.errors }}
             {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

The whole thing fails:

> Could not parse the remainder: '=='street'' from '=='street''

Comment: adding a space after the operator would probably work

Comment: thanks @hedde it now is not failing anmore...but it doesnt show the hr and the other stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template operators require a space before and after so replace

```
{% if field.type =='street' %}
```

with

```
{% if field.type == 'street' %}
```

or use the `ifequal` [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal)

```
{% ifequal field.type 'street' %}
    Hello world.
{% else %}
    Apocalypse
{% endifequal %}
```

Comment: hmm this does not work:         {% ifequal field.type 'street' %}
    <p>Hello world.</p>
{% endifequal %}

Comment: Then `field.type` isn't equal to `street`. An optional else clause will show you, see the updated example.

Comment: im my case street is also apocalypse ;-P   thanks for your help